# Firebase rest API filter query

Tags: java, error-handling, firebase

my data look like

```
{
  "word0" : {
    "level" : "B2",
    "meaning" : [ "Meaning19", "meaning43" ],
    "type" : "Noun",
    "weight" : 0,
    "word" : "word99"
  },
  "word1" : {
    "level" : "C1",
    "meaning" : [ "Meaning19", "meaning43" ],
    "type" : "Noun",
    "weight" : 0,
    "word" : "word99"
  },
  "word10" : {
    "level" : "A2",
    "meaning" : [ "Meaning19", "meaning43" ],
    "type" : "Noun",
    "weight" : 0,
    "word" : "word99"
  }
}
```

i am using curl get request `https://words-b6651.firebaseio.com/DE-EN.json?orderBy="$key"&print=pretty` and i want to get all words of a given level

is it possible to do something like $key."level" as in MongoDB ? and how could i get these data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can order by a property using:

```
https://words-b6651.firebaseio.com/DE-EN.json?orderBy="level"&print=pretty
```

Two notes:

- you'll need to [add an index to your Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data): `".indexOn": "level"`
- the items in the JSON will be in an undetermined order, since JSON is inherently non-ordered. This means that ordering in the REST API is really only useful when you also filter the data, e.g.

  ```
  https://words-b6651.firebaseio.com/DE-EN.json?orderBy="level"&equalTo="B2"&print=pretty
  ```

Comment: thanks that worked but sadly that the ordering is not useful until filtering

Comment: any way to request by curl(rest) - "word0" (mean - level, meaning, type, etc only for word0)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sending curl to your word's key path will return all of the values.

https://words-b6651.firebaseio.com/my/path/word10.json?&print=pretty