# Firebase sorting not working

Tags: sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm missing something or Fireabase just isn't sorting at all ??

https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy=%22height%22&print=pretty

```
{    
  "bruhathkayosaurus" : {
    "appeared" : -70000000,
    "height" : 25,
    "length" : 44,
    "order" : "saurischia",
    "vanished" : -70000000,
    "weight" : 135000
  },
  "lambeosaurus" : {
    "appeared" : -76000000,
    "height" : 2.1,
    "length" : 12.5,
    "order" : "ornithischia",
    "vanished" : -75000000,
    "weight" : 5000
  },
  "linhenykus" : {
    "appeared" : -85000000,
    "height" : 0.6,
    "length" : 1,
    "order" : "theropoda",
    "vanished" : -75000000,
    "weight" : 3
  },
  "pterodactyl" : {
    "appeared" : -150000000,
    "height" : 0.6,
    "length" : 0.8,
    "order" : "pterosauria",
    "vanished" : -148500000,
    "weight" : 2
  },
  "stegosaurus" : {
    "appeared" : -155000000,
    "height" : 4,
    "length" : 9,
    "order" : "ornithischia",
    "vanished" : -150000000,
    "weight" : 2500
  },
  "triceratops" : {
    "appeared" : -68000000,
    "height" : 3,
    "length" : 8,
    "order" : "ornithischia",
    "vanished" : -66000000,
    "weight" : 11000
  }
}
```

The heights are not sorted, is returning [44,...,0.6,...,3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request returns the result as a JSON object and there is no way to express the ordering, so the `orderBy` parameter cannot be used for ordering the results.

The `orderBy` parameter is expected to be used in conjunction with filtering parameters like `equalTo`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38592193/6680611).

Comment: Correct! For example: https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy=%22height%22&limitToLast=2&print=pretty