# Can not order data in firebase

Tags: javascript, json, api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a data like

```
{
"2017-11-01": {
"created_at": "2017-11-23 10:47:45",
"file_name": "qrcodes/1511434065790.png",
"qrvalue": "$2y$10$O8UcNz0TNvQdd3P3tfKNHe.OXVKC3KOQhtbZO9Sgl7x04sR.uTUhK",
"updated_at": "00-00-00 00:00:00",
"used": 1
},
"2017-11-21": {
"created_at": "2017-11-24 04:57:28",
"file_name": "qrcodes/15114994486172.png",
"qrvalue": "$2y$10$8QlU2d4o44YWw28h3pkAz.0EAclDxfAQfZQ6jR8VCAOznmdD5syPS",
"updated_at": "00-00-00 00:00:00",
"used": 2
},
"2017-11-24": {
"created_at": "2017-11-23 10:48:02",
"file_name": "qrcodes/15114340825347.png",
"qrvalue": "$2y$10$iiVr1FP4AYlAuhZEogSjMeeigjG1dMUnGm1A4XeK6EVF4HMogk2Lq",
"updated_at": "00-00-00 00:00:00",
"used": 0
}
}
```

and i have defined indexOn "used" in rules but while doing orderBy="used" its  not ordering accordingly.How can i order it by key value.

Comment: Can you show a snippet of code here

Comment: I am trying it on browser.Through url.

Comment: In that case: 1) show the URL in your question. Showing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) drastically increases your chances of getting help. 2) the results from a REST call aren't ordered, since JSON objects aren't ordered. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590700/firebase-rest-api-filter-query